# In a sharepoint .wsp file how do I move a folder full of files into the sharepoint filesystem

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I need to move a folder of files (+-100 or so) from within a .wsp file

Steps
1) Package up files into the wsp
2) When Feature is activated copy files to the filesystem (12\LAYOUTS\MyPackage)
3) When Feature removed delete the MyPackage folder
4) .......
5) Profit

The files do not need to be versioned etc by SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the module element within the elements.XML file referenced by your feature definition; details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The module element is correct.  To remove the files when you are done, use the code from [my post](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/02/16/linq-to-xml-and-deleting-files-on-feature-deactivation.aspx) which will delete any file that was created with the module element.